# How to use python modules in jepp?

Tags: java, python, jepp

I'd like to use python modules in my python code. But I think jepp cannot handle it properly.

**For example:**

```
>>>from  sklearn  import  linear_model    
>>>clf  =  linear_model.LinearRegression()    
>>>clf.fit  ([[0,  0],  [1,  1],  [2,  2]],  [0,  1,  2])    
>>>LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False)    
>>>clf.coef_    
>>>array([ 0.5,  0.5])
```

Jepp seems to run forever after the first line: no error message or exception(I call these lines from eclipse with jep.eval("script") ), but the code works if I run it from the python interpreter 'manually'.

**It doesn't work either if I use it in this way:**

```
>>>import sklearn
>>>clf  =  sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()
>>>...same as above...
```

> In this case I get the following error message: "SEVERE: null
>
> jep.JepException: jep.JepException: : 'module' object has
>
> no attribute 'linear_model'
>
> at jep.Jep.eval(Jep.java:294)
>
> at Main.executeScript(Main.java:72)
>
> at Main.main(Main.java:36)
>
> Caused by: jep.JepException: :
>   'module' object has no
>
> attribute 'linear_model'
>
> at jep.Jep.eval(Native Method)
>
> at jep.Jep.eval(Jep.java:278)
>
> ... 2 more"

**My only working version with modules is:**

> > > import numpy as np
> > >
> > > beta = np.array([1, 0.1, 10])

**So I need a solution in order to**

- use code: 'module.submodule.function'
- use import: 'import module.submodule' and use code: 'submodule.function'

Is it possible?

I'm using python 2.7.2 and jep 2.4 on Ubuntu 12.04. And I call the code above from eclipse, where I set these environment variables:

- LD_PRELOAD    /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
- LD_LIBRARY_PATH    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

I know there's a newer version of jepp but for me it was hard to configure 2.4. too, so I wouldn't install a newer if it's unnecessary.
(Because it was time-consuming for me. I had to compile a totally new python interpreter with ucs4, copy the installed python packages from dist-packages to site-packages, set environment variables and so on.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no Jepp for Python 2.7 on its [website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jepp/files/jep/2.4/) -- maybe that's at least part of the problem. You may need to install  the `python-2.6.4-vs7.1.msi` file from there to get a compatible version of the Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. 
I edited the post, because I didn't mention I use linux (Ubuntu 12.04). So I use jep.2.4 and installed it by: pip install jep.
I don't want to reinstall, unless someone can confirm that jep can handle code like:


 -  'module.submodule.function' OR


 -  use import: 'import module.submodule' and use code: submodule.function'


So jepp is capable of using modules and submodules like mentioned here? Because if it can't, I wouldn't try further.

Comment: Before you give up on Jepp, try using it directly instead via eclipse.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it. If I start 'jep' in command line, I get: 'Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jep.Run'. I followed the instructions from here:[project_site](https://github.com/mrj0/jep). I installed jepp with 'sudo pip install jep' and set the two environment variable: 'LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so' 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/'.

Comment: Then I downloaded the package 2.4.tar and run the 'python setup.py install' It manage to install, but If I run 'python setup.py test', I get 4 error in connection with (tests.test_jdbc.TestJdbc), for example:'ERROR: test_batch (tests.test_jdbc.TestJdbc)'

Comment: I don't give up until I find a solution, because it's needed for my MSc thesis, now I'm thinking of reinstalling the whole system, and start the jep installing process from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another sourceforge project called pyro4. It can handle python modules like: numpy, sklearn... And maybe it's even better because it is currently developed. (last jepp version was released in 2010)

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/mrj0/jep, that's where JEP is now. And it seems it was updated recently. As per the site it now works with Python version >= 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak for earlier versions of JEP, but I was able to run your script from the JEP 3.7.1 command line.  It uses Python 3.6.5.  I can also run the equivalent in Java 8.

C:>jep ... .... python\python36\Lib\site-packages\jep\console.py"

```
          No readline available. History will not be available.

               For Windows use pyreadline and get it from the official git
               repo on github:
               https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline

               Do NOT use the version on pypi.python.org, and therefore
               Do NOT use the version installed by pip.  It is out of date
               and doesn't work with Jep!
```

`>>>` from  sklearn  import  linear_model <-- JEP takes a few seconds for the import to process
`>>>` clf  =  linear_model.LinearRegression()
`>>>` clf.fit  ([[0,  0],  [1,  1],  [2,  2]],  [0,  1,  2]) 
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False) <-- JEP Returns
`>>>` clf.fit  ([[0,  0],  [1,  1],  [2,  2]],  [0,  1,  2])
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False) <-- JEP Returns
`>>>` clf.coef_
array([0.5, 0.5]) <-- JEP Returns
`>>>`

Answer (score 0):

I've found this [link](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Using+WEKA+via+Jepp) today.

It says: 'Jepp doesn't seem to be able to import third-party libraries like scipy, numpy or wx (pure Python modules can be imported, though).'

Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: I reinstalled the whole system and tried jepp on windows 7, and on Ubuntu 12.10 (compiled from source) but it still couldn't import sklearn

Answer (score -1):

Balazs, it will indeed import 3rd-party libraries.  One can do a `Jep.eval('import sklearn')` statement.